# How can I detect when an image is fully loaded?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have one VerticalLayout and I added one image component inside it. Sometimes , when we got poor connection , I noticed that this image is loaded slowly. So , I have an idea to show this image after fully loaded and I would like to show some loading gif while loading.

Since I am using **GWT** , I use [LoadHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html#onLoad%28%29) for this situation as below

```
fullSizeImage.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
        public void onLoad(final LoadEvent event) {
            loadingImage.setVisible(false);
        }
});
```

Above snippet will show my loading gif image while my actual image was loading and it will hide when my acutal image was fully loaded. How can I figure it out in **Vaadin** ?

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin is on server side and its components actually don't have all possible GWT methods. So when you create the image component it gets attached to the parent VerticalLayout. Then the image is loaded by a server request from the client.

I think there is no way around to create a custom Vaadin widget - or extend the existing functionality - which implements your GWT code above. Please note that the loading gif should be prefetched and cached by the client to display it immediately when the component gets attached.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Upload](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Upload.html) component. It offers a few features that helps with monitoring the upload process (start/progress/finish).

[Here](http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples-vaadin7/book/#component.upload.basic) is an official example how to use the `Upload.Receiver`, `Upload.StartedListener` and `Upload.SucceededListener` interfaces (take a closer look at `ImageReceiver` class).

I hope it helps.